# disable/ignore cookies with httpclient

Tags: android, cookies, httpclient

How can I disable/ignore default cookie handling of httpclient. I want to do it manually. I want to set a pre-defined cookie header for all http requests.

Answer (score 8):

The latest httpclient **(4.5.1)** has a method called `"disableCookieManagement"`, and it appears this just disables the internal cookie management, not the ability to send or receive cookies, and is working for me-

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html#disableCookieManagement()

Answer (score 1):

Set `httpclient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);` before you execute your `HttpClient`

Comment: But I don't see the api setCookieStore() :(

Comment: are you using `DefaultHttpClient`?

Comment: yes..I am using the default http client in android for my http requests

Answer (score 1):

Force to setup the HttpContext before executing the request:

```
private HttpClientContext httpContext = new HttpClientContext();
httpContext.setCookieStore(new BasicCookieStore());
```

The setCookieStore will create an empty cookie store to replace the default cookie store of http connection.

After that we can execute the http method:

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpClient.execute(HttpUriRequest, HttpContext)
```

Also we can reuse the cookie store (hold the `BasicCookieStore`) to keep the connection alive.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to disable/ignore cookie handling by DefaultHttpClient in Andoroid(I should have explored more into Android source code but have a time limitation). But I resolved it by removing all cookies before doing httpClient.execute() like this -

```
((AbstractHttpClient) myDefaultHttpClient).getCookieStore().clear();
```

This removes all the cookies stored by the defaultHttpClient and then you can manually handle(add/delete) cookies using -

```
myHttpPost.setHeader("Cookie", myCookie);
```

Hope it helps.